# Fetch data from two tables in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have to fetch students data, whose account status is true from Student and User tables.as account status has been mentioned in User table and remaining information of the student is in student table,i need students registered under particular college since i have to check college_id in where condition.I have tried many ways to join tables but getting error,please help me to get out of this. below is my code

```
Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select stud.student_name, stud.college.college_id, stud.enroll_no, stud.enrollment_year from Student stud,User u where stud.college.college_id=:college_id and u.account_active=:account_active");
        query.setParameter("college_id", college_Id);
        query.setParameter("account_active", true);
        List<Student> list_1 = query.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to join by using pojo like below

```
Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("
select stud.student_name, stud.college.college_id, stud.enroll_no, stud.enrollment_year 
from User u
join u.Student stud
join stud.college college
where college.college_id=:college_id 
and u.account_active=:account_active
");
query.setParameter("college_id", college_Id);
query.setParameter("account_active", true);
List<Student> list_1 = query.list()
```

if Student relationship is availabe in your `User` table and all pojo must have object of another table in there pojo

Comment: still not working,actually college is an object in student pojo,i have tried given solution but didn't work,if possible will you please elaborate this ?

Comment: can u tell me relationship between these table
means how table having fk and pk relation

Comment: ok, Student pojo consist of students information like this @Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {}

Comment: no am asking about just fk.. like student table having fk of college so what about user and student table

Comment: basically there is no as such relationship between these two,students are mapped with college_id,when student get registered is college id gets inserted into user table as User_id and similarly its account_active status which is by default set as false,but by making it true,i have to show only students with acount active status true

Comment: 'select stud.student_name, stud.college.college_id, stud.enroll_no, stud.enrollment_year 
from User u
join u.college college
join college.Student stud
where college.college_id=:college_id 
and u.account_active=:account_active'
so it will work but  u must have reverse relationship too in all pojo

Comment: ok,i will try this one and will let you know again if I stuck somewhere